# Exporting query results in a csv file with oracle procedures

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

i need to create a procedure that take as a parameter a query and the result of that query should be exported in a csv file but i can't find a solution, can you help me please?

Comment: Where does the file need to be created? On the database server, or on the client?

Comment: must be created on the client

Comment: You won't be able to do that with a stored procedure. PL/SQL can only see `DIRECTORY` objects on the server. Any file creation on the client must be performed by an application that runs on the client. The application could call the procedure to return the data, but the app would have to create and populate the csv file.

Comment: What about in the database server can you help me?

Comment: Please read "Why is Help Me not a question"(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and "How to Ask" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), then post a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the error(s) you are getting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As you're passing *any query* to a stored procedure (though, I'd rather suggest a function), you can't know which columns will be involved so that you could "prepare" local variables or something like that. Certainly, what comes in mind is **ref cursor** that's being returned from the function I previously mentioned.

Here's an example; see if it helps.

Function; `par_query` is a query you'll pass as function's parameter. It (the function) then returns ref cursor.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_query in varchar2)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for par_query;
  7    return rc;
  8  end;
  9  /

Function created.
```

Let's test it:

```
SQL> var l_rc refcursor
SQL> begin
  2    :l_rc := f_test('select d.dname, e.ename, e.job, e.sal from emp e join dept d ' ||
  3                    'on e.deptno = d.deptno where d.deptno = 10 '                   ||
  4                    'order by d.deptno, e.ename');
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

`l_rc` now contains result of the query that was passed to the function. Let's store it into the file. How? Spool! File will be stored on your own PC (therefore, you don't have to have access to the database server).

```
SQL> spool test.txt
SQL> print l_rc

DNAME          ENAME      JOB              SAL
-------------- ---------- --------- ----------
ACCOUNTING     CLARK      MANAGER         2450
ACCOUNTING     KING       PRESIDENT       5000
ACCOUNTING     MILLER     CLERK           1300

SQL> spool off
```

That's it. What's the file contents?

```
SQL> $type test.txt
SQL> print l_rc

DNAME          ENAME      JOB              SAL
-------------- ---------- --------- ----------
ACCOUNTING     CLARK      MANAGER         2450
ACCOUNTING     KING       PRESIDENT       5000
ACCOUNTING     MILLER     CLERK           1300

SQL> spool off
```

Kind of *works*. Make it pretty if you want.